# Changing an existing field's format without dropping, recreating

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I've tried changing the format attribute of a field (from Text to URL) without dropping the column and recreating it. I know this isn't supported, but it seemed simple so I thought I'd give it a try.

I came up with this SQL script based on [this post](https://debajmecrm.com/2014/04/12/change-field-data-type-in-mscrm-without-dropping-and-recreating-the-field/)

```
UPDATE Attribute SET AttributeLogicalTypeId = 'url' WHERE AttributeId in 
(
    SELECT AttributeId FROM Attribute ab where ab.LogicalName in ('new_linkedin') and ab.EntityId in 
    (Select  EntityId from Entity where LogicalName in ('account', 'contact'))
)
```

According to the UI, when I go back in the field's configuration, this seems to have worked. But the problem is the value in the field is never turned into an actual URL, whereas the built-in field `websiteurl` does it properly (value turns bold and underlined).

Am I missing something else to update in the database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, removing the field from the form(s), publishing the form(s) and then putting the field back on the form(s) and publish yet again did it.